# # Id selector in react css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I'm using React Css modules for styling my react app.

I have some html elements with id attribute and I want to style them using the css id selector and not a class selector. Is that possible with react css modules? For example.

This is an example of css, I'm going to call it Button.modules.css

```
#specialButon {
 margin: 5px;
}

.notSpecialButton {
 margin: 5px;
}
```

And this is an example of react component

```
import style from './Button.module.css';

function Button() {

 render(
  <div>
   <button id="specialButon">Special<button>
   <button className={style.notSpecialButton}>Not Special<button>
  </div>
)

export default Button
```

Could you tell me, How can I use de id selector to apply style elements?

Thanks you.

Comment: The same way you apply a class:
`id="style.specialButon"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, you can use global CSS in React which is generally in `App.js`.
But is general to use `className` in module CSS.

Answer (score 9):

It's a bit late, but the accepted answer is actually not a right one. You can definitely use **id** selectors with **CSS Module**!

In your case, just changing it to the below will do ***:)***

```html
<button id={style.specialButon}>Special<button>
```

or

```html
<button id={style['specialButon']>Special<button>
```

Comment: And referring to an id within CSS module remains the same, correct? As in, #id{….} ?

Comment: this only works as you suggest because actual CSS id uses camel case. If you use proper kebab case like `#special-button` then it would only work like `style['special-button']`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes its totally OK to use id's in CSS Modules.**

Component.js

```js
<button id={style.specialButon}>Special<button>
or
<button id={style.specialButon}>Special<button>
```

style.module.css

```css
#specialButon{
margin: 5px;
color:red;
}
```