# How to make clip-path work in react using CSS modules

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, jsx, css-modules

The following `clip-path` doesn't seem to be working while the syntax seems to be accurate. Although, I suspect there might be a problem the way I am referencing my `Id` (I learnt the way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401865/19119712 and I do not wish to declare or refer to the `Id` globally).

Basically, the image above the `SVG` needs to be clipped along the `path` mentioned in the `SVG`.

```
      <img
        className={styles.clip_container}
        src={bgImg}
        alt="Processor chipset image."
      />
      <svg
        className={styles.svg}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.0"
        width="1280.000000pt"
        height="673.000000pt"
        viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 673.000000"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      >
        <defs>
          <clipPath id={styles.one}>
            <path d="M1060 5660 l0 -970 975 0 975 0 0 970 0 970 -975 0 -975 0 0 -970z" />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
```

The SCSS in modules:

```
.clip_container {
  // z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 550px;
  clip-path: url(#one);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#one);
}

.svg{
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

I am quite aware of masking images as an alternative but I need clip-path for a particular animation. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is `styles.one`? Change it to `<clipPath id="one">` and it might work. It needs to match the id used in you css `clip-path: url(#one)`

Comment: The thing is, I’m using CSS modules in my project and hence styles.one. I’ll still give it a try and let you know what happens but I am doubtful it’s going to work. In any case, thank you for the suggestion and I’m also open to any other ideas you may have.

Comment: What did you define in your CSS module that you hope to reference via `<clipPath id={styles.one}>`? It's not a class selector, is it? You can only use an ID, but ID selectors don't get prefixed with a hash by css modules. And they don't get exported as far as I know, so this should result in `styles.one === undefined` in your current code.

Comment: Hey! So if you check out the question again, I've provided the SCSS which is from the CSS module for the component and no it's not a class selector. Also, from what I understand from your comment, `ID`s cannot be used for reference in `clipPath` `url`s  when working with CSS modules is it? Or is it that CSS modules doesn’t facilitate `ID`s at all? If so, are you aware of any other way I can implement `clipPath`?

Comment: The first thing you should try is: does a hardcoded ID work? if that's the case you can start to tackle the second concern: you could use a custom css variable to share a generated ID between the component code and the css style.

Comment: Turns out, hardcoded ID is working! But before I deal with organising my files and CSS, there's a new problem: I tried multiple SVGs but with each of those either only a small portion of the image is being clipped along the SVG or the image is clipped altogether. Basically, I now need the image to be clipped exactly along the SVG path that I provide. I suppose it is an SVG problem now instead of an ID problem. In any case, thanks for helping with the ID problem and I'm open to any ideas you may have for the current issue as well.